# Cassandra upgrade from 2.1.13 to 2.2.9

Tags: cassandra, upgrade

Could any advise the procedure for upgrade cassandra from 2.1.13 to 2.2.9?
Do I need to run nodetool upgradesstables?
And does the application need to make any change?
looks the authentication table has been changed,any action need to do?

many thanks.

Comment: Thanks.it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Running upgradesstable is a best practise and should be ran on any update.

Review this article about compatibility:

https://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/CompatibilityGuarantees

About authentication, best way is to do the upgrade in some isolated environment (not prod) and see if all is ok.